# Is there a cli command to get information of older versions of packages in debian-based distributions?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, package-management, dpkg

By package information, I mean this example info I got using `dpkg -p bash` or `apt-cache show bash`

```
Package: bash
Essential: yes
Priority: required
Section: shells
Installed-Size: 1656
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Architecture: amd64
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 5.0-6ubuntu1
Replaces: bash-completion (<< 20060301-0), bash-doc (<= 2.05-1)
Depends: base-files (>= 2.1.12), debianutils (>= 2.15)
Pre-Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libtinfo6 (>= 6)
Recommends: bash-completion (>= 20060301-0)
Suggests: bash-doc
Conflicts: bash-completion (<< 20060301-0)
Filename: pool/main/b/bash/bash_5.0-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Size: 638400
MD5sum: d2655b78815a8ccd61674828408d27cd
Description: GNU Bourne Again SHell
Original-Maintainer: Matthias Klose <doko@debian.org>
SHA1: b1a0d6a9bae4b70616b93403be1f485742ba8162
SHA256: 3ee861fb5a1ea976e97a9038f785b43252bd4040cdd066ea1afe675ff7625ec8
Homepage: http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashtop.html
Task: minimal
Description-md5: 3522aa7b4374048d6450e348a5bb45d9
```

These commands give info for the latest package only. I want a command where I can specify any version of the package and get its information.

Comment: Debian (rather than the implementation) usually limits itself to one version per repository. So you get only one version (or two when there's a recent new security version). By comparison, wine packages from the external repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian offer all past versions (today, I can count 50 versions for bullseye's winehq-staging).

Comment: So I don't know of a CLI, but there's for Debian (not Ubuntu, but your tag is Debian, not Ubuntu while your package is an Ubuntu package): https://snapshot.debian.org/binary/bash/ . If you are looking for Ubuntu answers, you should put the Ubuntu tag.

Comment: This is a general query for debain as well as debian-based distributions which includes Ubuntu. The example is from ubuntu. I would even appreciate if different commands for different distros solve the question. I am adding the ubuntu tag as well.

Comment: But my comments tell it doesn't depend on apt or dpkg, but on the choice of each debian-based distribution. I gave an example of a separate entity (WineHQ) which is using a different choice

Comment: I got you. The fact that package managers do not provide direct commands for info of all versions is sad.